# Find a formula for $1 + 3 + 5 + ... +(2n - 1)$, for $n \ge 1$, and prove that your formula is correct.

Tags: summation, induction

I think the formula is $n^2$.

Define $p(n): 1 + 3 + 5 + \ldots +(2n − 1) = n^2$

Then $p(n + 1): 1 + 3 + 5 + \ldots +(2n − 1) + 2n = (n + 1)^2$

So  $p(n + 1): n^2 + 2n = (n + 1)^2$

The equality above is incorrect, so either my formula is wrong or my proof of the implication is wrong or both.

Can you elaborate?

Thanks.

Comment: You are wrong about $p(n+1)$. The last term should be $2n+1$.

Comment: How/why is the last term $2n + 1$?

Comment: $p(n+1)=1+3+5+\ldots+(2n-1)+(2(n+1)-1)$ 
$=1+3+5+\ldots+(2n-1)+(2n+1)$

Comment: Because all the terms of $p(n+1)$ are supposed to be odd, and $2n$ is even, not odd.

Comment: [Something](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697629) to help you *visualize* the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that $p(n+1)$ is note the statement 
$$
1+3+5+\cdots+(2n-1)+2n=(n+1)^2;
$$ 
it is the statement 
$$
1+3+5+\cdots+(2n-1)+(2n+1)=(n+1)^2.
$$

Why?  The left side of your formula is the sum of all odd numbers between $1$ and $2n-1$. So, when you replace $n$ by $n+1$, you get the sum of all odd numbers between $1$ and $2(n+1)-1=2n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the series as 
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 2i-1$$
Continuing,
$$...=2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1$$
$$=2\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n$$
$$=n^2+n-n$$
$$=n^2$$

As you expected.

Comment: Awesome stuff !

Answer (score 1):

$p(n): 1 + 3 + 5 + \ldots +(2n − 1) = n^2$

$p(n + 1): 1 + 3 + 5 + \ldots +(2n − 1) + 2n+1 =n^2+2n+1= (n + 1)^2$
next term after $2n-1$ is $2n+1$ is not $2n$ as you mean

Answer (score 1):

$n^2 - (n-1)^2 = 2n - 1$ might be the main part of a proof.