# Which numbers can be realized in the form $a^x - b^x$ for $a, b$ of opposite parity and $x$ even?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

> How can we check whether a number can be represented in the form of $a^x - b^x$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers of opposite parity and $x$ is positive and even integer.

I thougth of using $$a^n - b^n = (a - b) (a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdots + b^{n-2}a +b^{n-1}) .$$

Comment: What is $c$?   I found no $c$ there

Comment: Presumably $c$ is meant to be $x$.

Comment: @Azlif Sorry, made the changes

Comment: @TravisWillse right.

Comment: Well  $a^x - b^x = (a^{\frac x2} - b^{\frac x2})(a^{\frac x2} + b^{\frac x2})$.

Comment: Do you mean to restrict to $x$ nonnegative? Positive?

Comment: @TravisWillse Positive

Comment: @fleablood Could not get the use of it.

Comment: Note:  $2k -1= k^2 - (k-1)^2$.  Let $x = 2$ and $N$ be any odd number.  Even numbers are impossible.

Comment: Practically identical question from same user here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417387/which-numbers-can-be-realized-in-the-form-ax-bx-for-a-b-of-opposite-par

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that every odd prime number can be written as a difference of two squares.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810753/prove-that-every-odd-prime-number-can-be-written-as-a-difference-of-two-squares)

Answer (score 3):

If $a,b$ have different parity then $a^x - b^x$ must be odd.

And if $x$ is even then $a^x - b^x = (a^{\frac x2} - b^{\frac x2})(a^{\frac x2} + b^{\frac x2})$

So for any odd $2k-1$, the $a = k; b=k-1; x= 2$ and $2k-1= (k-(k-1))(k+(k-1)) =k^2 - (k-1)^2$

So all odd numbers and only odd numbers can be so represented.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810753/prove-that-every-odd-prime-number-can-be-written-as-a-difference-of-two-squares#comment1676488_810806

Comment: a and b should be natural numbers

Comment: then how 1 can be formed

Comment: Can you please help me in that

Comment: $1 = 1^2 - 0^2$.

Comment: If $a,b$ are not allowed to be $0$ then $1=a^2 -b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ where requires $a+b=a-b =\pm 1$ which can only be solved by $a=1;b=0$ so $1$ is the only number that can not be don't.  Any *other* odd number, except $-1$, can be done by $2k-1= k^2 - (k-1)^2$ (note $k$ can be negative).  If $2k-1$ is prime then $a=k$ and $b=k-1$ is the only way but if $2k-1=m*n$ is composite that $a-b=m,a+b=n$ or $a=\frac{m+n}2$ and $b=\frac{n-m}2$ will also be a solutions. (and if $a$ and $b$ both squares $x=4$ and $a'=\sqrt a; b'=\sqrt b$ will work as well)

Comment: "a and b should be natural numbers"  Well, you should have *said* something about that then.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For $x = 2 m$, we have
$$a^x - b^x = (a^m)^2 - (b^m)^2 ,$$
that is, any difference of even powers is a difference of squares, so we may as well restrict our attention to $x = 2$.

Now, the factorization of a difference of squares is $$a^2 - b^2 = (a + b) (a - b) ,$$ which specializes the factorization formula in the question statement.

> **Additional hint** Since $a$ and $b$ have opposite parity, $a - b$ and $a + b$ are both odd, hence so is $a^2 - b^2$. Are all odd numbers expressible this way?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810753/prove-that-every-odd-prime-number-can-be-written-as-a-difference-of-two-squares#comment1676488_810806

Comment: a and b should be natural numbers

Comment: Everything in my answer applies just as well in that case, though the solution is slightly different if you do not include $0$ in the natural numbers

Comment: When we do not include 0 then I think 1 would not be counted.

Comment: Am I correct for above reason?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417487/how-to-be-in-the-form-of-ax-bx

Comment: That's correct: If $(a + b)(a - b) = 1$ and we have $a, b \geq 1$, then $2 \leq a + b = \pm 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: So what could be the solution

Comment: The hint (and additional hint) in my question get you most of the way there. The next step is to try to realize a general odd number in the form $a^2 - b^2$; you can do this using the factorization.

Comment: I think there would be only one case that is x =1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100574/discussion-between-yfusav-and-travis-willse).

Comment: Is there something wrong

Comment: I don't think I can be much more specific without giving the rest of the problem away, though note that if $n$ cannot be realized in the form $a^x - b^x$ then neither can $-n$ (since we can just switch the roles of $a$ and $b$).