# Find and prove formula

Tags: proof-writing, induction

For $n\in \Bbb N$, find and prove a formula for $$\sum_{i=1}^n(2i-1)$$

How do I use induction to find a formula for it? I haven't not encountered any question like this in my textbook.

Comment: Take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940146/prove-by-induction-that-1357-2n1-n12-for-every-n-in-mathbb?rq=1

Comment: @mfl second one

Comment: @RobertZ but in this case there's no right side

Comment: Try out few values of $n$, do you see a pattern? If so can you prove it by induction? In general induction can't be used to find an expression but only to prove it.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: For guessing the right side see the picture here: http://www.9math.com/book/sum-first-n-odd-natural-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to go by induction, you first need a formula.

Start with $n=1$, then the sum is $1$.

For $n=2$, the sum is $1+3 = 4$.

For $n=3$, the sum is $1+3+5 = 9$.

With this in mind, you can see that the sum "seems" to be $n^2$ (it's an intelligent guess , it's difficult to say how you would do this in a more general situation). This can be proved inductively.

Base case : We know that for $n=1$, the sum is $n^2 = 1^2 = 1$.

Inductive Case : Suppose that this is true for $n$ i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1) = n^2$. Simply add $2n+1$ to both sides, and note that $2n+1 = 2(n+1) - 1$.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (2i-1) = \sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1) + (2(n+1)-1) = n^2 + 2n+1 = (n+1)^2
$$

Hence, the proposition is true for $n+1$, hence the proposition is true for all $n$ by induction.

The intuition for guessing $n^2$ comes from the well known formula that $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Substituting this formula in the expression  $\sum (2i-1)$ gave me back $n^2$, so I could use this for induction.

Comment: how did u come up with the formula, i get its $n^2$, but how did u get it

Comment: As I said earlier, it's an intelligent guess. I will try and give an intuition of this fact, but this guess comes from my familiarity with sequenes. You see, in the starting everybody would struggle with this question, because one doesn't know what to guess. It's only with experience that you can guess. Of course, the first step has got to be : compute the value for small $n$, and then look for a pattern. For example, you see a pattern in $1,2,4,8,16,...$, right? That's why, you shouldn't put your head down if you couldn't guess this : another year and you will be wondering how you did not.

Comment: Having said that, induction without a formula is extremely difficult. So if you're given a problem and said : "solve by induction" without being given a formula, then it would be difficult to simplify the expression. For example, there is a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^4$, but you (and I, to be fair) wouldn't be able to guess it by looking at the terms and thinking of a formula. Such a problem will have to be tackled differently.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** If you have not yet formed a conjecture about what it might be, here are the first couple terms:
$$\sum_{i=1}^1 (2i-1)=1$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^2 (2i-1)=4$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 (2i-1)=9$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^4 (2i-1)=16$$

Do you see a pattern? Once you have formed a conjecture, I can give you some tips about how to prove your conjecture using induction.

Answer (score 2):

Use $1+2+3+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)=2\sum_{i=1}^{n}i-n=2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-n=n^2+n-n=n^2$$