# A property regarding complete/perfect squares.

Tags: square-numbers

> When a set of natural numbers is under consideration,
>   if we add first consecutive 'n' odd natural numbers(i.e. from 1 )  we get a complete square whose root is 'n' itself.

```
e.g. first 5 consecutive odd natural numbers are,
1,3,5,7,9 so, 
1+3+5+7+9 = 25.
We get √25 = 5 .
or 
e.g. first 6 consecutive odd natural numbers are,
1,3,5,7,9,11 so,
1+3+5+7+9+11 = 36
We get √36 = 6 .
```

I observed this while working on an algorithm to identify perfect squares.
Has this been observed by any mathematician before?

Comment: Boy, is this well known. However, your discovering it by yourself is good. Don't worry whether some you discovered is new - it probably is not. That does not matter.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697629) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606483).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's kind of amazing isn't it! To explain we have:
Odd number $2i-1$

$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)
  &=2\sum_{i=1}^{n}i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}1 \\
  &=\frac{2(n)(n-1)}{2}+n \\
  &=n^{2}-n+n=n^2
\end{align}$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this fact is widely known. Look, for example, this diagram:

[image]

Comment: Nice elaboration.. Thank you!