# The effect on the total area of two equal triangles when decreasing/increasing the height by the same amount.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

We have two equal right triangles $A$ and $B$ with slope $-\lambda$ where the two bases span the distance between $t$ and $t+1$.

[image: Figure 1]

The sum of both areas we call $X$.

Let's say we decrease and increase the height of both triangles respectively by the same amount $\theta$.
This means the area of $A$ is decreased with the area $C$ and the area of $B$ is increased with the area $D$.

[image: Figure 2]

If we shift them back between $t$ and $t+1$, this gives us the new $A$ and $B$ triangles like in the below figure.

[image: Figure 3]

The area of the new $A$ and $B$ triangles is larger than $X$, because $D \gt C$.
If we measure the difference, this is equal to $\frac{1}{\lambda}\theta^2$. This is because

[image: Figure 4]

My question is: is this a known identity ?

Comment: It reminds me of an identity dealing with the sum of consecutive first $n$ **odd** numbers : $1+3+5+...+(2n-1)=n^2.$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1666850/305862)).

Comment: Is an explanation involving calculus acceptable?

Comment: An analytical point of view is always useful to add.

Comment: It seems the final result is incorrect. My calculation shows it equals $\frac{1}\lambda \theta^2$

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I used $\lambda$ as the slope. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the original triangle be base $x$ and height $h$, so $h=\lambda x$, area $A=B=\frac{1}2\lambda x^2$. If we decrease the height for triangle $A$, we get a new triangle $A'$ with height $h'_A=h-\theta$, the new triangle is similar to the original triangle, so we have

$$\frac{h}{h_A'}=\frac{x}{x_A'}\Rightarrow x_A'=x-\frac{\theta}{\lambda}$$

If we increase the height for triangle $B$, we get a new triangle $B'$ with height $h'_B=h+\theta$, the new triangle is similar to the original triangle, so we have

$$\frac{h}{h_B'}=\frac{x}{x_B'}\Rightarrow x_B'=x+\frac{\theta}{\lambda}$$

The difference for the sum of areas:

$$\begin{align}A'+B'-A-B&=\frac{1}2\lambda (x_A')^2+\frac{1}2\lambda (x_B')^2-\frac{1}2\lambda x^2-\frac{1}2\lambda x^2\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}\theta^2\end{align}$$